# How to restore the original firmware on D-link DI-514 router?

Tags: router, firmware, reset

I bought a used D-link DI-514 router and it had some problems, and the reset button on it seems not to be working.
I tried to update its firmware but something went wrong, now I can't even access 192.168.0.1. 
I tried to do a crash reset but the reset button but it is not working. I tried pushing it 10 sec, 30 sec, power on, power off, everything and nothing happened. I don't know what to do. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have bricked the device.

Comment: Oh. That's what I was afraid of. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you do the upgrade over wireless? You are supposed to be wired when you flash these devices.

Comment: No offense, but this device is so outdated and obsolete (it sells for less than $10 on eBay used, and new models can be found for under $25) just get a new one. The wireless only supports 802.11b (which is ancient and doesn't even support WPA2 encryption) and can't handle a throughput of much over 20Mb/s even on the wired ports. In the days of 1 or 2 Mb/s Internet service, this was a bottom of the line entry model at best. This was released in 2010 and hasn't been updated in over 4 years, it is a nightmare security risk. Put it to rest, a new $40 router will blow this away in every regard.

Comment: @acejavelin, while I totally agree with you, I try to refrain from putting to much opinion in my posts. I don't know if the op wants to use this for arduinos or some micro controller that has a serial bit rate over wireless. At any rate, I was just trying to help the guy keeping in mind he may not have money for a new router right now.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I don't mean to detract from your answer... It is completely valid. My point is in most situations, but not all, putting any time into attempting to recover the device may not be worth the effort. The asker may not be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a couple of reasons, the image you uploaded was corrupted, you loaded the wrong image, you corrupted the bit by bit transfer by loading the firmware via wireless etc.

1. Plug the Ethernet cable that connects your computer to the router plugged into one of the LAN ports,
2. Setup your PC with static IP - like 192.168.0.2 (different from 192.168.0.1)
3. Make sure the PC has the new firmware
4. Unplug the power
5. Hold the reset button for 3~5 seconds and re plug the power WITHOUT RELEASING THE RESET BUTTON.
   (Make absolutely sure you have the correct image for your device)
   6.Open a web browser to 192.168.0.1 and then you should see EMERGENCY FLASHING page then click browse/upload locate the file and click UPLOAD FIRMWARE NOW

Note: This process can be tedious, and more then likely you will have to try steps 4-6 a couple times before you see the emergency recovery page.

If this doesn't work you may have to try the tftp method.

Good luck, I hope you breath life into your router again.